# WebStart of Java EAR application failing from Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-3, java-web-start

I built a small test Java EE Entreprise Application using NetBeans. Everything works fine in NetBeans (version 7.3) when I run/debug it.

I'm now trying to deploy the test app using WebStart. To do so, I have setup a GlassFish server of the same version that is in NetBeans (GF 3.1.2.2) and I have the JDK Version 7 U 51 installed on the machine. For right now, I'm trying to run the WebStart app on the same machine that GlassFish is on so I'm guessing it's using JRE 7U51 also.

However, when I launch the client application from within GlassFish admin page (app deployed fine), I get a NullPointerException.

Here's the full exception trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.JWSAppClientContainerMain.insertMaskingLoader(JWSAppClientContainerMain.java:186)
    at org.glassfish.appclient.client.JWSAppClientContainerMain.main(JWSAppClientContainerMain.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Here's the JNPL file I get from GlassFish when I want to WebStart the application:
http://pastebin.com/HPddJA3a

Please note that the JNPL file is autogenerated by GlassFish... my EAR doesn't contain one.

This is my first deployment and I've tried many things.... please help! :)

**EDIT:** More details on how I deploy and access the client app:

I uploaded the EAR file to Glassfish using the admin console (port 4848) and that deployment is successful (no error messages). Then, in the admin console, I see all my EE components (EJB, app jar, etc) and I can launch the client app. This just links to the following URL: http://server-test.com:8080/EEAppTest/EEAppTestEEClient (not a real URL). When I access it, I get the NullPointerException described above.

Comment: *"WebStart of Java EAR application failing from Glassfish 3.1.2.2"*  Does that mean it works OK when you *don't* use GlassFish?

Comment: Do you mean by running the client stub jar using appstart? I have not tried that, I'll be at work in about 30 minutes and will be trying it. If that's not what you mean.. what did you mean? :)

Comment: *"client stub jar using appstart?"*  Never heard of either of them.  I meant when you set it up to launch from a link (to a plain JNLP) from an HTML page, does it work or fail?

Comment: I have not yet built an HTML page to launch a java app using a custom made JNPL. I'm new to this whole thing. To date, I have uploaded the EAR file to Glassfish using the admin console (port 4848) and that deployment is successful (no error messages). Then, in the admin console, I see all my EE components (EJB, app jar, etc) and I can launch the client app. This just links to the following URL: http://server:8080/EEAppTest/EEAppTestEEClient

When I access this URL, I get the NPE (NullPointerException) described above.

Comment: If your new to JWS you should start at the 'shallow end' with HTML/static JNLP.  Don't go throwing technologies in on top of that (is my advice).

Comment: try this first:  https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/entappclient.html   and then try to deploy it after you get it running.